# ExtJS + Django. How to submit form with POST method

Tags: django, extjs

Firstly, I should say that I checked all threads at stackoverflow that have some connection to my topic, but I still could not get a working solution. So, now when I try to submit a form I get error: `'Forbidden (403). CSRF verification failed. Request aborted....'`. I do it like this:

```
var frm=Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
    method:'POST',
    standardSubmit:false,
    items:[{
         xtype:'textarea',
         name:'sourcecode',
         value:sourcecode
    }]
})

frm.getForm().submit({url:'/myapp/saveSourceCode'})
```

In fact, I do not know how to send `CSRF cookie`. All suggestion, that I have seen do not help at all. So, I need the simplest working demo, that will demonstrate in the simplest possible way how we should send forms with POST method. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here comes from the **CSRF cooki**.

You can try this ( from the [WC3 school docs](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) )

Example (not tested) :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
} 


var csrf = getcookie('csrftoken')

var frm=Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
method:'POST',
standardSubmit:false,
items:[{
     csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrf,
     xtype:'textarea',
     name:'sourcecode',
     value:sourcecode
}]
})

frm.getForm().submit({url:'/myapp/saveSourceCode'})
```

Hope this helps.